# int-ws:inbound-gateway SoapExceptionResolver

Tags: web-services, soap, spring-integration

Can anyone tell me where the spring integration ws:inbound-gateway sets its SOAP Exception Resolver?
The outbound gateway has an attribute that I can set but the inbound does not.
I ant to set the Soap Fault Details before returning the SOAPFault back to the caller.
I have looked through the AbstractSoapFaultDefinitionExceptionResolver and tried to trace it back to somewhere where I could set it but I seem to be failing.

Any chance some one could point me in the right direction.

*************UPDATE************
just as an FYI this was my final solution based on Artem's suggestion:

```
<bean id="exceptionResolver"
    class="com.cloud.utils.CloudSoapFaultDefinitionResolver">
    <property name="defaultFault" value="SERVER" />
</bean>


public class CloudMessagingSoapFaultDefinitionResolver extends SoapFaultAnnotationExceptionResolver {
private Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(getClass());
private static final int THREE = 3;

/* (non-Javadoc)
 * @see org.springframework.ws.soap.server.endpoint.AbstractSoapFaultDefinitionExceptionResolver#customizeFault(java.lang.Object, java.lang.Exception, org.springframework.ws.soap.SoapFault)
 */
@Override
protected void customizeFault(Object endpoint, Exception ex, SoapFault fault) {
    SoapFaultDetail details = fault.addFaultDetail();
    Method[] methods = ex.getClass().getDeclaredMethods();
    if (ex instanceof MonitiseCloudServicesException) {
        AbstractRuntimeException mcse = (AbstractRuntimeException) ex;
        methods = mcse.getClass().getDeclaredMethods();
    }
    for(Method m:methods){
        addDetailsElement(ex, details, m);
    }
}

/**
 * @param ex
 * @param details
 * @param m
 */
private void addDetailsElement(Exception ex, SoapFaultDetail details, Method m) {
    if(m.getName().startsWith("get")){
        SoapFaultDetailElement element = details.addFaultDetailElement(new QName(m.getName().substring(THREE)));
        try {
            element.addText((String) m.invoke(ex, new Object[]{}));
        } catch (IllegalAccessException | IllegalArgumentException
                | InvocationTargetException e) {
            log.error("An error occured processing the SOAPFault detail node {}.",m.getName().substring(THREE));
        }
    }
}

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually don't mix `inbound` and `outbound` parts. They are `server` and `client` respectivally, from Spring WS perspective. They have just a different nature for configuration.

So, on server part you can do that like this:

```
<bean id="exceptionResolver"
    class="org.springframework.ws.soap.server.endpoint.SoapFaultMappingExceptionResolver">
    <property name="defaultFault" value="SERVER"/>
    <property name="exceptionMappings">
        <value>
            org.springframework.oxm.ValidationFailureException=CLIENT,Invalid request
        </value>
    </property>
</bean>
```

That's because any Spring Integration `<ws:inbound-gateway>` is a part of standard Spring WS `MessageDispatcherServlet` configuration:

```
<bean class="org.springframework.ws.server.endpoint.mapping.UriEndpointMapping"
      p:defaultEndpoint-ref="ws-inbound-gateway"/>
```

And all `Faul Resolving` work is done by Spring WS.